# Evolution Calendar sometimes has error 403 with my Google Calendar?

Tags: 20.04, sync, evolution, calendar, google-calendar

So this problem never appeared before this started happening like 1 week ago.

Sometimes I get an Error 403 when syncing to the Google Calendar and Google tasks, but this only happens with the Ubuntu internal Google sync, when I sync manually in Evolution, it works, but the Google Tasks don't get synced.
When I logout and wait for like 5 minutes and then log back on it suddenly starts working again.
It's really annoying sometimes.

So my question is:

- Is it possible to sync Google Tasks manually?
- Or can I somehow fix this problem?

I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Additionally I need to say that my Google account does not have a Google-Mail address

Comment: In a terminal window, `sudo journalctl --since="-10 minutes"` within 10 minutes of the `403`

Comment: I'm running into this issue too, any solutions yet?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: so what I did now.

Comment: The issue comes from Gnome Online Accounts an the OAuth from Google. What I did is switching to Mozilla Thunderbird. With the TbSync Addon, connecting to Google Calendar is so easy and I did not run into any errors. When you still want to persist with Evolution, you can try activating `Third Party Apps` in the security tab on your google account. This could sometimes resolve your issue.